# How to quickly check if peaceful mode enable/disable

Tags: factorio

I created a game with the largest starting base parameter. I forgot if I checked or not the peaceful mode case before seeding the map.

Is there a way to access this information?

Comment: Please change the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot check if it was enabled or not. However, what you can do is enable/disable it with the console.

Go to options and look at the keybinding to open the lua console. You can find the binding in the game tab.

Once you open the console, type the following command

`/c game.player.surface.peaceful_mode=BOOL`

Replace BOOL with TRUE if you want to enable it or FALSE if you want to disable it.

You can have a look at all the other commands [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/factorio/comments/4qchhv/013_list_of_helpful_console_commands/).

Keep in mind that using console commands **will disable achievements**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for notifying us that "using console commands will disable achievements".

There is an another way I found to check and keep achievement on: players can look in achievements tab if those that require peaceful mode off are still possible. If in peaceful, they will be marked as "impossible". But it requires at least one not achieved yet.

Comment: Maybe you don't know so much about the Factorio Lua API, but `game.player.surface.peaceful_mode` is a read/write property, so it is possible to read it as well. See my answer.

Comment: @SimonForsberg You're right, I dont know much about lua, but I think this is a bit more about how the game implements the commands. Anyway, I think the accepted answer should change to yours.

Comment: @TheBird956 If you don't want to edit your own answer, and of course that's fine, you can delete it (unless it being accepted prevents you from doing that, which it might).

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following console command to check whether or not peaceful mode is enabled:

```
/c game.player.print(game.player.surface.peaceful_mode);
```

Keep in mind that using console commands **will disable achievements**, but you can save your game, run the command, and reload your game afterwards to avoid achievements from being disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Certain achievements are locked on peaceful mode. You can check by opening up the achievements menu (the trophy icon on the top right), and seeing if the "There is no spoon" achievement has the message "This achievement cannot be unlocked in peaceful mode."

I'm not sure if this method works if you have already gotten "There is no spoon," but it is quick, easy, and doesn't require console commands or disabling achievements.

[image: The achievements button in Factorio]

Achievement button

[image: Part of the achievements screen in Factorio, showing the achievements "No time for chitchat" and "There is no spoon" as unavailable, with the meesage "This achievement cannot be unlocked in peaceful mode."]
Achievement screen